# how to add sitemap in woocommerce product website?

Tags: woocommerce, product, sitemap

how to add sitemap in woocommerce product website

I was able to include the individual products posts without any issue. However none of the categories are being added. I believe Woocommerce is saving product categories as custom Tags.

Also, the ability to set a different priority for custom posts (and tags in the future) would be great!

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: http://australianritual.com/ is the website when i add sitemap to this it won't reflect please help